# How to use different WHERE clauses for each column

Tags: mysql

I think this should be simple but I'm not sure how to do it.

I want to write a SQL query that will output three columns: week, number of apples, and number of oranges.

Say my database looks like this:

```
week              | fruit_type | fruit_num
------------------------------------------
6/17/2013 0:00:00 | Apples     | 4
6/17/2013 0:00:00 | Oranges    | 3
6/24/2013 0:00:00 | Oranges    | 1
6/24/2013 0:00:00 | Apples     | 2
6/24/2013 0:00:00 | Apples     | 7
```

I would like the query to output this:

```
week              | Apples | Oranges
------------------------------------------
6/17/2013 0:00:00 | 4      | 3
6/24/2013 0:00:00 | 9      | 1
```

I can get Apples and Oranges individually like this:

```
select 
date_trunc('week',week) as "Week", 
sum(fruit_type) as "Apples"
from table 
where fruit_type = 'Apples'
group by date_trunc('week',week)
order by date_trunc('week',week)
```

but would obviously prefer to generate both columns with the same query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what date_trunc is so I left that out. You can either use a JOIN command to join queries, or do it with a single query by combining SUM with CASE:

```
SELECT week,
SUM(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'Apples' THEN fruit_num END) as 'Apples',
SUM(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'Oranges' THEN fruit_num END) as 'Oranges'
from fruit
group by week
order by week
```

Example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69bfb/2

Comment: Recommend that you also do `WHERE fruit_type IN ('Apples','Oranges')` to give the optimizer a shot.  There might be more fruits, and you only care about those two in this query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use case statements. You apply the conditions while doing the select, so no need for the where clause.

```
SELECT
date_trunc('week',week) as "Week", 
[Apples] = SUM(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'Apples' THEN fruit_num END),
[Oranges] = SUM(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'Oranges' THEN fruit_num END)

FROM 
table

GROUP BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
date_trunc('week',week) as "Week", 
CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'Apples' THEN sum(fruit_type) as "Apples",
CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'oranges' THEN sum(fruit_type) as "Oranges"
from table 
group by date_trunc('week',week)
order by date_trunc('week',week)
```

Comment: 'LIKE' is unnecessary - you should use '=' instead. You only need LIKE when using wildcards.

Comment: yeah if some people enter the data with typo it would be useful.

Comment: Not without a wildcard being specified, it isn't. It won't match `Apples2` without a wildcard, even with LIKE; you'd need LIKE 'Apples%' or 'Apples_' for it to work. (Unless, of course, the non-standard, strange syntax allowable under MySQL allows it to work, in which case there's one more reason to avoid MySQL.)

Comment: @KenWhite : yes My bad. I will make the changes to my post.